# JHipster Version 7.9.3 Using Local Blueprint Gives npm ERR! 404 Not Found

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-blueprint

I use JFrog to manage my npm repository and have already created a virtual directory in which the blueprint exists (as part of the local directory).  I have the following in my ~/.npmrc:

```
//jaiashirwaad.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/default-npm-virtual/:_auth = asdfaasdfasdf23e234wadefasdfasdfasdfasd
email = info@mycompany.com
always-auth = true
```

I get the following when running the command: `jhipster --blueprints saathratri-cassandra-blueprint jdl --skip-fake-data apps.jh`:

```
INFO! Generator app child process exited with code 1idealTree:node_modules/string-width/node_modules/strip-ansi Completed in 1ms
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-jhipster-saathratri-cassandra-blueprint - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'generator-jhipster-saathratri-cassandra-blueprint@7.9.3' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/amar/.npm/_logs/2023-01-20T22_36_39_488Z-debug-0.log
ERROR! Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
    at makeError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:60:11)
    at handlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/execa/index.js:118:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 1: npm install',
  command: 'npm install',
  escapedCommand: 'npm install',
  exitCode: 1,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,
  stdout: undefined,
  stderr: undefined,
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false
}
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-jhipster-saathratri-cassandra-blueprint - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'generator-jhipster-saathratri-cassandra-blueprint@7.9.3' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/amar/.npm/_logs/2023-01-20T22_36_55_013Z-debug-0.log
ERROR! Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
INFO! Generator app child process exited with code 1
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
    at makeError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:60:11)
    at handlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/execa/index.js:118:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 1: npm install',
  command: 'npm install',
  escapedCommand: 'npm install',
  exitCode: 1,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,
  stdout: undefined,
  stderr: undefined,
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried putting a .npmrc file in your project root directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue.  I noticed the following in the package.json files of my services:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "generator-jhipster": "7.6.0",
    "generator-jhipster-saathratri-cassandra-blueprint": "7.6.0",
    "prettier": "2.5.1",
    "prettier-plugin-java": "1.6.1",
    "prettier-plugin-packagejson": "2.2.15"
  },
```

Perhaps I could have changed the line

```
 "generator-jhipster-saathratri-cassandra-blueprint": "7.6.0",
```

to

```
  "generator-jhipster-saathratri-cassandra-blueprint": "file:../relative/path/to/generator-jhipster-saathratri-cassandra-blueprint",
```

and the error would go away but I did not want to since it would involve me injecting my version of package.json.ejs myself in my blueprint.

I decided to search for the word "package.json" and "package.json.ejs" in the generator-jhipster directory and found:
In options.js:

```
  'skip-jhipster-dependencies': {
    desc: "Don't add generator-jhipster and blueprints to package.json.",
    type: Boolean,
  },
```

and then search for skipJhipsterDependencies and found:

```
<%_ if (!skipJhipsterDependencies) { _%>
    "generator-jhipster": "<%= packagejs.version %>",
  <%_ otherModules.forEach(module => { _%>
    "<%= module.name %>": "<%= module.version %>",
  <%_ }); _%>
<%_ } _%>
```

in package.json.ejs.

So I figured, from the above results, there was a way of not outputting my local blueprint in the services package.json's devDependencies section.

So I tried changing the command I run to: `jhipster --blueprints saathratri-cassandra-blueprint jdl --skip-fake-data --skip-jhipster-dependencies apps.jh` and that did the trick.  No more 404 error.